# How to Associate a Radio Button to Another Radio Button with Different Name

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button

I want another radio button to get checked once another radio is checked. The two buttons have different names.

At the moment radio button A is checked, B should get checked as well.

```
<input type="hidden" name="menu_date[<?php $date_name ?>]" value="<?php echo $result['date']; ?>" />

<input type="radio" name="Menus[<?php echo $random_name; ?>]" value="<?php echo $result['foodMenuID']; ?>" id="Menus_1" for="menu_date[<?php $date_name ?>]" <?php echo $radio_state; ?>/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question correctly.

If you have something like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="Menus[<?php echo $random_name; ?>]" value="<?php echo $result['foodMenuID']; ?>" id="Menus_1" for="menu_date[<?php $date_name ?>]" <?php echo $radio_state; ?>>
<input type="radio" name="Menus[<?php echo $random_name; ?>]" value="<?php echo $result['foodMenuID']; ?>" id="Menus_2" for="menu_date[<?php $date_name ?>]" <?php echo $radio_state; ?>>
```

Then add `onclick` event to the first radio button:

```
<input type="radio" name="Menus[<?php echo $random_name; ?>]" value="<?php echo $result['foodMenuID']; ?>" id="Menus_1" for="menu_date[<?php $date_name ?>]" <?php echo $radio_state; ?> onclick="markOther()">
```

And then write a very simple JavaScript function:

```
function markOther()
{
    document.getElementById('Menus_2').checked = true;
}
```

Please note that only 1 radio button can be selected with the same name (if they contain different names, like you said, then it will work). In this case, only the second will be selected, even you click on the first.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that: 
Here are two names "sort" and "animal"

```js
document.getElementById("herb").onclick = function()
{
 if (document.getElementById("herb").checked) 
   {                                      
 document.getElementById("cow").checked="qq"; 
   }
}

document.getElementById("meat").onclick = function()
{
  if (document.getElementById("meat").checked) 
   {
     document.getElementById("tiger").checked="qq";
   }
}
```

```html
<h1> Choose your favorite animal</h1>
<form id="mainForm" name="mainForm">
    <input type="radio" name="sort" id="herb" />Herbivores </br>
    <input type="radio" name="sort" id="meat" />Carnivore </br> </br>

 
    <input type="radio" name="animal" id="cow"/>cow </br>
    <input type="radio" name="animal" id="duck" />duck </br>
 <input type="radio" name="animal" id="buffalo" />buffalo </br> </br>
 
 <input type="radio" name="animal" id="lion"/>Lion </br>
    <input type="radio" name="animal" id="croco" />Crocodile </br>
 <input type="radio" name="animal" id="tiger" />Tiger </br>

</form>
```

if you want any modification you are welcome.